# Where can I find the ["SITE_NAME"] attribute from the HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, http-error

Please find the screenshot below:

[image]

Where can I find the highlighted ["SITE_NAME"] field?

Comment: That's a placeholder for **INSERT YOUR SITENAME HERE**.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the steps listed in the error, namely:

[Enable or Disable Directory Browsing in IIS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109(v=ws.10).aspx)

[Configuring Default Documents in IIS 7](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753615(v=ws.10).aspx)

Also, [SITE_NAME] is whatever the URL of your website is, such as www.costco.com.